# How to get x-axis value in chart as string?

Tags: javascript, html, chart.js

I am trying to plot a graph using chart.js where y-axis values are numbers and x-axis values are strings. I have given the code that i have written, but it does not plot the string values.
Appreciate your help.

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var dataPoints7 = [];

  var chart7 = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer7", {
    animationEnabled: true,
    theme: "light2",
    title: {
      text: "Cases in States"
    },
    axisY: {
      title: "Cases",
      titleFontSize: 24
    },
    data: [{
      type: "line",
      yValueFormatString: "#,### Cases",
      dataPoints: dataPoints7
    }]
  });
  fetch("https://api.covid19india.org/data.json", {
      "method": "GET"
    })
    .then(function(response) {
      return response.json();
    })
    .then(function(data) {
      for (var i = 1; i < data.statewise.length; i++) {
        dataPoints7.push({
          x: data.statewise[i].state,
          y: parseInt(data.statewise[i].confirmed)
        });
      }
      chart7.render();
    });
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<div id="chartContainer7" style="height: 370px; width: 100%;"></div>
<script src="https://canvasjs.com/assets/script/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://canvasjs.com/assets/script/canvasjs.min.js"></script>

</html>
```

Comment: Don't use `window.onload`, your HTML declares that you're using modern HTML, so don't use JS patterns from the HTML4.01 / 1998 era (all the `on...` attributes and properties are purely legacy at this point). Load your script with `<script src="..." defer></script>` so that your code is _guaranteed_ to run only after the document has loaded. With that said: if the problem is that things don't draw correctly, remove all the code that's unrelated to that. Just hardcode a single datapoint, remove everything except that function inside the last `then`, and show what happens.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

For your case you should supply `label` ***property*** not `x` value and also i believe you should use column charts for this purpose.

You might see some labels not showing up.You can either set the angle or increase the width of chart to make it visible.

Try running this snippet

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var dataPoints7 = [];

  var chart7 = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer7", {
    animationEnabled: true,
    theme: "light2",
    title: {
      text: "Cases in States"
    },
    axisY: {
      title: "Cases",
      titleFontSize: 24
    },
    axisX: {
      labelAngle: 180
    },
    data: [{
      type: "line",
      yValueFormatString: "#,### Cases",
      dataPoints: dataPoints7
    }]
  });
  fetch("https://api.covid19india.org/data.json", {
      "method": "GET"
    })
    .then(function(response) {
      return response.json();
    })
    .then(function(data) {
      for (var i = 1; i < data.statewise.length; i++) {
        dataPoints7.push({
          label: data.statewise[i].state,
          y: parseInt(data.statewise[i].confirmed)
        });
      }
      chart7.render();
    });

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<div id="chartContainer7" style="height: 370px; width: 100%;"></div>
<script src="https://canvasjs.com/assets/script/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://canvasjs.com/assets/script/canvasjs.min.js"></script>

</html>
```

Comment: Try setting properties in axisX labelAngle: -45, interval:1 to show all but its not looking good